# Using pattern on a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a set of code that takes user inputs and attempts to match it against a set of `String`s. I was wondering if it was possible to use pattern on a specific variable. I will put values on the variables that I would like to use.

```
if (twojunglers[0].equals("hecarim")){
    if (twojunglers[1].equals("leesin")) {
        String regexe = "(?>=Champion Red).{43}";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexe);
        String abc* = br.readLine();

        //I'd like to do something like this but for obvious reasons it wont work String str = p.abc;
        int cutstring = abc.lastIndexOf("%");
        String stuffs_ = abc;

        if (cutstring >= 0) stuffs_ = abc.substring(0, cutstring);
        System.out.println(stuffs_ + "%");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you please try to express bit more?

Comment: Thankou for the edits Sky Luke.

Comment: I was wondering if I could apply the regexe to the string somehow because currently it is unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one simple example that illustrates how to find a digit `String` from the given alphanumeric `String`:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {

   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
      String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
      }else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\bpow\\w+)(.*?)(\\bener\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Test powers test energies test.");

if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```